# Dojo build (shrinksafe) using Maven project id in embedded html

Tags: maven, dojo, maven-antrun-plugin

I'm using the Dojo build utility (i.e. shrinksafe) from Maven to build Dojo JavaScript template widgets into one file. For some reason, when I do the build it substitutes the ${id} tag in the HTML template snippets I use with the Maven project id (group/artifact/package/version):

```
'my/application/ui/Calculator':function(){
require({cache:{
'url:my/application/ui/templates/Calculator.html':"<div class=\"${baseClass}\">\r\n<div id=\"my.app:noddy-calc:war:1.0.0-RELEASE_button\"
```

instead of:

```
'my/application/ui/Calculator':function(){
require({cache:{
'url:my/application/ui/templates/Calculator.html':"<div class=\"${baseClass}\">\r\n<div id=\"${id}_button\"
```

Has anyone come across this weird behaviour and (more importantly) is there any way of preventing it?

In the Maven pom, I'm using the ant plugin to run shrinksafe:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
...
<executions>
    <execution>
        <tasks>
            <java classname="org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main" fork="true" maxmemory="512m" failonerror="true" classpath="${js.build.directory}/util/shrinksafe/js.jar;${js.build.directory}/util/closureCompiler/compiler.jar;${js.build.directory}/util/shrinksafe/shrinksafe.jar">
                <arg value="${js.build.directory}/dojo/dojo.js"/>
                <arg value="baseUrl=${js.build.directory}/dojo"/>
                <arg value="load=build"/>
                <arg line="--profile ${dojo.build.profileFile}"/>
            </java>
        </tasks>
```

Comment: I've found an answer, although not an explanation.

Comment: I noticed that other segments of embedded html, from other files, did have the ${id} characters correctly declared. I had a look at the files and they didn't seem to be any different from the offending html. I've always thought that if you can't see anything wrong, what's wrong might be what you can't see. I compared the files in a text editor that can show the end-of-line symbols in the file. The correct one had Unix-style, LF, the wrong one had Windows, CR-LF. I converted the wrong one to Unix which fixed the problem. Not the best solution, though.